# WPF MVVM - Public Property of View Model cannot be found in data binding

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a WPF / MVVM Light application. (sorry for long post, I'm trying to be thorough, and maybe I regret ever using WPF)

In one of my views, I have 5 combo boxes that bind their "SelectedValue" to the property of an object inside my ViewModel called "Selection"

The view itself is a user control and the user control sets its DataContext to the viewmodel.  As a result, the ItemsSource of these comboboxes is set through a relative binding, that links to a public property of type Observable Collection.

Here is how three of the combo boxes are defined in the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="FTC.View.JobListView"
             x:Name="ParentControl"            
             DataContext="{Binding JobList_VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
    ...
      <ContentControl Name="Selection" DataContext="{Binding Path=Selection, Mode=TwoWay}">
          <Grid Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailControl}">
            ...
              <ComboBox Name="IdClient" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" Width="300"
                        Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailComboBox}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.ClientViewSource.View}"
                        SelectedValuePath="idClient"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding idClient, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="chrCompany"></ComboBox>

              <TextBlock Text="Quoted By" Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailLabelSub}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,10,0,11"/>
              <ComboBox Name="IdQuoteBy" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailComboBox}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                      Path=DataContext.EmployeeQuotedCVS.View}"
                        SelectedValuePath="idEmployee"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding idQuoteBy, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="LegalName" Margin="3,3,0,6" IsEditable="True" ></ComboBox>

              <TextBlock Text="Project Manager" Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailLabelSub}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="3,11,0,10"/>
              <ComboBox Name="IdCoOrdinator" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailComboBox}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ParentControl,Path=DataContext.EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS.View}"
                        SelectedValuePath="idEmployee"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding idCoOrdinator, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="LegalName" Margin="3,3,0,6"  IsEditable="True">
              </ComboBox>
          ...
          </Grid>
      </ContentControl>
      ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here are the three related properties defined in the view model:

```
Private _clients As New ObservableCollection(Of client)
Private _employees As New ObservableCollection(Of employee)

Private _clientCollectionViewSource As New CollectionViewSource
Private _employeeQuotedCvs As New CollectionViewSource
Private _employeeCoOrdinatorCvs As New CollectionViewSource

Public Property Clients As ObservableCollection(Of client)
    Get
        Return _clients
    End Get
    Set
        _clients = Value
        RaisePropertyChanged(ClientCollectionPropertyName)
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ClientViewSource As CollectionViewSource
    Get
        Return _clientCollectionViewSource
    End Get
    Set
        If _clientCollectionViewSource Is Value Then
            Return
        End If
        _clientCollectionViewSource = Value
        RaisePropertyChanged(ClientListCollectionPropertyName)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Employees As ObservableCollection(Of employee)
    Get
        Return _employees
    End Get
    Set
        _employees = Value
        RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeeCollectionPropertyName)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property EmployeeQuotedCvs As CollectionViewSource
    Get
        Return _employeeQuotedCvs
    End Get
    Set
        If _employeeQuotedCvs Is Value Then
            Return
        End If
        _employeeQuotedCvs = Value
        RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeeQuotedCvsPropertyName)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property EmployeeCoOrdinatorCvs As CollectionViewSource
    Get
        Return _employeeCoOrdinatorCvs
    End Get
    Set
        If _employeeCoOrdinatorCvs Is Value Then
            Return
        End If
        _employeeCoOrdinatorCvs = Value
        RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeeCoOrdinatorCvsPropertyName)
    End Set
End Property
```

### PROBLEM

The problem is that the "clients" combo box displays records while the "employees" ones do not.  I get the following binding erros on the employee comboboxes:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :  BindingExpression path error:
>   'EmployeeQuotedCVS' property not found on 'object' ''JobListViewModel'
>   (HashCode=31919989)'. 
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.EmployeeQuotedCVS.View; 
>   DataItem='JobListView' **(Name='')**;  target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name='IdQuoteBy');  target property is 'ItemsSource' (type
>   'IEnumerable')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :  BindingExpression path error:
>   'EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS' property not found on 'object'
>   ''JobListViewModel' (HashCode=62499712)'. 
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS.View; 
>   DataItem='JobListView' **(Name='ParentControl')**;  target element is
>   'ComboBox' (Name='IdCoOrdinator');  target property is 'ItemsSource'
>   (type 'IEnumerable')

I can see from the error that the **EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS** is not found on the ViewMoobjectectr.  but you can see in the code I posted that they are public properties.

### WHAT I TRIED

1. I confirmed that the employees observable collection does have records in the view model
2. I used snoop to delve into the bindings, I can confirm that at the user control level the public property **EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS** is there and if I delve deeper, I can see in snoop that there are records present.
   [image]
3. I tried using a relative source binding to the user control as well as naming the user control and using a ElementName binding.  You can see this in both errors above.  It did not work, same problem.
4. I tried moving the employee combo boxes outside the content control to top level inside the user control, the error still appears, and there are no records.

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out why using a relativeSource/ElementName binding for the combo box's itemSource cannot find the property it needs in the view model?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The property names are `EmployeeQuotedCvs` and  `EmployeeCoOrdinatorCvs`, while your Binding Paths use `EmployeeQuotedCVS` and `EmployeeCoOrdinatorCVS`. WPF is case sensitive.

Comment: thank you so much @Clemens, I can't believe I missed that.  I recently refactored some code including consistent naming conventions for variables and these properties stopped working.  Fixing the case-sensitive names solved it for me.  If you add this as an answer I will accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I wish Intellisense extended to the xaml to catch when this happens. Maybe one day Microsoft....

Comment: @Tronald ha ha, so true!